# how to export the tables into a csv file pandas

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

The following is a piece of code I wrote to create a pivot table for categorical vs continuous variable.

```
for row in categorical:
    for col in numeric:
        ptable = pd.pivot_table(df, values = col, index = row, aggfunc = ['min','max','median','mean','std',lambda x: 100*x.count()/df.shape[0]])
        print(ptable)
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('report.xlsx')
        ptable.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
        writer.save()
```

It displays the output as in the image:[image: click fo image]

but this is not a data frame and when writing into an excel file it displays only the last iteration values.
[image: click image]

how do I get all the iterated tables into the excel file or separate excel files?

Answer (score 1):

Your current code overwrites the previous sheet, which is why only the last iteration is present. Setting each sheet to the same name (`Sheet1`) will overwrite the sheet. This name will need to be changed for each interation.

Try this:

```
for row_index, row in enumerate(categorical):
    for col_index, col in enumerate(numeric):
        ptable = pd.pivot_table(df, values = col, index = row, aggfunc = ['min','max','median','mean','std',lambda x: 100*x.count()/df.shape[0]])
        print(ptable)
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('report.xlsx')
        ptable.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1_{}_{}'.format(row_index, col_index))
        writer.save()
```

This should save each iteration as an individual sheet

Comment: i ran into the following error:                                                                       
Exception: Excel worksheet name 'Sheet1_Runners-Up_QualifiedTeams' must be <= 31 chars.

Comment: Instead of writing it into different CSV, is it possible to convert the ptable into dataframes??